# PIP install not recognizing versions

Tags: python, pip, pypi, semantic-versioning

I have a custom pypi server, that I am installing files from. I attempt to upgrade from version 0.0.1 to a newer version of my own custom module. It is not detecting the later version.  When I do a `pip install 'mymodule>=17'` I see:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mymodule>=17 
(from versions: 17.0828.222133-e1e0fd9, 17.0828.222305-e1e0fd9, 
17.830.210154-e1e0fd9, 0.0.1)
```

Notice the versions show up, but it will never detect the 17.X versions with the git sha on the end. Ideas? Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the hyphen, `17.0828.222133-e1e0fd9` and the like are not valid version specifiers as defined in [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).  As a result, they are treated as "legacy version" strings by [pip's internals](http://packaging.readthedocs.io) and are sorted less than all valid version strings.  Hence, as far as pip is concerned, these versions are not greater than 17.

Comment: Thank you!  This was the understanding I was looking for.  Thanks again.